# Confused what a glyph is, in pdf parsing

Tags: parsing, pdf

//Text object of a decoded text stream in a pdf

```
q
0.750 0.000 0.000 -0.750 0.000 841.890 cm
0.000 g
/F10 10.667 Tf
0 Tr
0.000 Tc
BT
1 0 0 -1 189.306 981.342 Tm
[<0003><0047><0052>-1<0048><0056><0051>33<006e>11<0057><0003><0052><0051><004f><005c><0003><004f><0052>7<005a>9<0048><0055><0003><005c>10<0052><0058><0055><0003><0046>5<0052><0056><0057><0056><0003><0003><0049>12<0052><0055><0003><0046>5<0052><0051><0056><0044><0051>3<0057><0056>8<0011>]TJ
ET
Q
```

What are the glyphs of above TJ entry and how to identify a glyph separately?

Comment: You have to look up the properties of the referenced font **F10**. It *appears* to have an **Identity-H** encoding referring to a common internal TTF glyph ID mapping. But this appearance may deceive.

Comment: when placing this text, we need to calculate a Tm and a Trm from glyph to glyph, I'm asking whether to take the hexa strings from an integer to another integer or to take one 2 byte hexa string as a unit to calculate the Trm.

Comment: You have to look up the properties of the referenced font **F10**. It *appears* to have a two-byte encoding but it could also be a single-byte encoding with the glyph at 0x00 being used every other position. Or it could be a mixed encoding. Depending on that you will get different numbers of glyphs in those strings.